# Abrir imagens em segundo plano

Tags: php, imagem

Pretendo saber se é possível, ao carregar uma página web, as imagens não interfiram no carregamento da página, isto é, ao abrir a página execute e só depois leia as imagens, para a página demorar a abrir 1 segundo e não 3, por exemplo.

Como consigo fazer tal coisa?

Comment: Todo HTML já carrega em separado das imagens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o plugin [LazyLoad](https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/) para carregar as imagens apenas quando as mesmas estiverem na área visível da tela do navegador.

*A vantagem disso é que há um ganho de performance no carregamento da página e poupa também consumo de banda de internet dos usuários, ainda mais quando os mesmos acessam seu site via 3G ou 4G.*

O uso do Lazy Load é simples. Basta adicionar o script na `<head>` da sua página:

```
<script language="javascript" src="jquery.lazyload.js"></script>
```

Em seguida adicionar a class `.lazy` nas imagens que serão afetadas:

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="imagem_real.png" src="imagem_pre.png" />
```

E chamar a função no script:

```
<script>
$(function(){$("img.lazy").lazyload();});
</script>
```

Notas:

- `data-original` é o caminho da imagem final, que será carregada
  quando a área em que ela está estiver dentro da área visível do
  navegador.
- Em `src` você coloca o caminho de uma imagem genérica, que será
  pré-carregada antes da imagem final (crie uma imagem mais leve
  possível, como um png de 1x1 pixel, por exemplo).

> Baixe o plugin e veja a documentação no link
>   https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/

Comment: É o comentário que mais se enquadra ao que procuro. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar alguma técnica de lazy loading em javascript para fazer isso de forma assíncrona.

Existem alguns plugins para isto, como por exemplo:
https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/

Leia mais: 
https://www.sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance/