# Carregamento de slide no momento de execução

Tags: php, javascript, html, imagem

Eu possuo um site com muitas imagens , dessa forma a primeira vez que o usuário abre o site ele demora muito pra carregar por que primeiro carrega as imagens que estão no topo do site pra depois carregar o resto da pagina.
Eu queria saber como deixar a minha estrutura da mesma forma ( sem alterar o visual ) e fazer com que o usuário carregue todo o corpo do site pra depois carregar as imagens.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Abrir imagens em segundo plano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234023/abrir-imagens-em-segundo-plano)

Comment: Arthur, dá uma olhada neste resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/234137/8063

Comment: No caso como funciona esse lazyload amigo ?Desculpe duplicar.

Comment: Não é grande problema duplicar. Isso acontece. Dá uma olhada na resposta, é muito simples, mas é preciso usar jQuery.

Comment: Eu poderia sem usar ele ( porque teria que gerar imagens com qualidades menores certo?) configurar pras imagens carregar por útlimo?

Comment: O Lazy Load funciona assim: onde estão as imagens, ele irá carregar apenas 1 imagem padrão (pode ser 1 .png transparente de 1 pixel, super leve) e só carregará as outras caso elas apareçam no view.

Comment: Ou seja, as imagens que o usuário não viu, não serão nem carregadas.

Comment: Ata , entendi , vou realizar uns test então , muito obrigado brother você salvou banda do meu servidor.

Comment: Uma útlima pergunta , essa imagens é baixada quando ela aparecer parar o usuário?Nesse caso eu tenho slideshow e ela so vai ser baixada quando aparecer?

Comment: Não use em slides... use apenas para imagens estáticas do site

Comment: é porque os slides estão provocando isso , as imagens que constituem ele são muito pesadas pois são puxadas do imdb e nesse slide possui 50 , 100 fotos por isso queria pririzar o carregamento do resto da pagina .

Comment: Aí o problema estaria mais direcionado ao slider. Realmente carregar esse tanto de foto não é bom. Teria que ver a estrutura desse slider para poder fazer com que ele carregue apenas a imagem que está sendo visualizada e não carregar antes tudo.

Comment: Você fala plugin em que sentido?

Comment: Fui eu quem criei com ajuda de um site , ele é simples , vou pegar o codigo.

Comment: Código:https://pastebin.com/BEnTEeXt

Comment: Sé você perceber ele puxa as imagens do banco pra gerar o html da imagens que é grande.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analisando seu [código](https://pastebin.com/BEnTEeXt), para evitar que a imagem seja carregada antes de aparecer no slider, crie um *dataset* com o caminho da imagem em vez de colocar no `src` (no `src`, deixe vazio ou coloque uma imagem padrão leve):

```
<img src="" data-img="<?=imagem?>"...
```

Criei uma função separada para carregar as imagens:

```
function preImg(i,x){
   imgidx = i == 2 ? 0 : 1;
   var imagem = x[i-1].childNodes[3].childNodes[imgidx].childNodes[imgidx];
   imagem.src = imagem.dataset.img;
}
```

Isso irá carregar a imagem apenas quando ela estiver na sua vez no slider.

Exemplo:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      preImg(slideIndex,x);
    setTimeout(carousel, 7000);
}
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    preImg(slideIndex,x);
}

function preImg(i,x){
   imgidx = i == 2 ? 0 : 1;
   var imagem = x[i-1].childNodes[3].childNodes[imgidx].childNodes[imgidx];
   imagem.src = imagem.dataset.img;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
   <div class="text">
      <a href="xxxxxx<?=$xxxxxx?>" ><?=$xxxxxx?></a>
   </div>
  <a href="xxxxxxxx?>" >
   <center>
   <img height="227" width="500" src="" data-img="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" style="width:100%">
   </center>
   </a>
<br>
  </div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="text"><a href="xxxxxx<?=$xxxxxx?>" ><?=$xxxxxx?></a></div>
  <a href="xxxxxxxx?>" ><center><img height="227" width="500" src="" data-img="https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/hrc-tigre-siberiano-2-jpg_21253111.jpg" style="width:100%"></center></a>
<br>
  </div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Amigo , não funcionou , a imagem não é exibida :/

Comment: Codigo:
https://pastebin.com/tG2PvY1y

Comment: Colocou `preImg(slideIndex,x);` dentro das duas funções?

Comment: Como está na resposta?

Comment: Eu copie como estava na sua reposta , o print do resultado está assim:https://i.imgur.com/N0TARux.png

Comment: Console:https://i.imgur.com/zORjjFg.png

Comment: Dentro da função `preImg`, troque os `slideIndex` por `i`

Comment: Não deu certo também, to tentando editar aqui so que não ta rolando.

Comment: Ok.. vou dar uma analisada melhor

Comment: Eu acho que deve ser algo no showSlides porque mudamos pro date-img ai o codigo original não funciona , to testando aqui algumas coisas sé der certo reporto aqui , mas espero sua reposta!

Comment: Beleza , entendi amigo , acho que o erro foi na hora de setar o child nodes , tentei assim:
[code]x[slideIndex-1].childNodes[3].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].src = imagem.dataset.img;[/code]

Comment: Substitui assim:
[code]function preImg(slideIndex,x){
    var imagem = x[slideIndex-1].childNodes[3].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
    x[slideIndex-1].childNodes[3].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].src = imagem.dataset.img;
}
[/code]

Comment: Adicione na sua solução lá , muito obrigado!